# Microsoft MVC "echo/print/output" etc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

With ASP.NET's view engine/template aspx/ashx pages the way to spit to screen seems to be:

```
<%= Person.Name %>
```

Which was fine with webforms as alot of model data was bound to controls programatically. But with MVC we are now using this syntax more oftern.

The issue I have with it is quite trivial, but annoying either way. This is that it seems to break up the mark up i.e.:

```
<% foreach(var Person in People) { %>
    <%= Person.Name %>
<% } %>
```

That seems like alot of opening and closing tags to me!

Other view engines in the MVC contrib have a means of spitting to screen with out opening and closing the script tags using standard keyword such as "print, out, echo" i.e. (brail example):

```
<% 
for element in list:
      output "<li>${element}</li>" 
end
%>
```

Now, I said this may seem trivial, but it just seems more readable this way. So what are the advantages of MS having this syntax, and not providing a output method?

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider something like this, instead:

```
<% foreach(var Person in People) { 
    Response.Write(Person.Name); 
} %>
```

I believe that'll work. (Although I haven't tested it; I've only just begun with MVC and don't have the toolset here at the office.)

EDIT: I apparently missed the actual question ... :)

Microsoft does provide an output method, but didn't provide a syntax like the one you describe. The output method is `Response.Write()`. I can't answer this directly (I believe you'll need to check with Scott Hanselmann over at MS :)), but I think they didn't want to complicate scripting by adding yet-another-language for us to learn; I think they wanted to leverage the languages (C#, VB, etc.) which developers already knew.

EDIT #2: I placed the following in a comment, and in retrospect (for completeness), it should be part of the answer.

If you head over to the [Learn MVC site on ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-04-cs.aspx), in the view tutorial (that's the link), you'll see the following paragraph:

> Since you call `Response.Write()` so
>   often, Microsoft provides you with a
>   shortcut for calling the
>   `Response.Write()` method. The view in
>   Listing 3 uses the delimiters `<%=` and
>   `%>` as a shortcut for calling
>   `Response.Write()`.

Essentially, `<%= %>` is the accepted shortcut for `Response.Write`, and you therefore can use the full `Response.Write` method anywhere you'd use `<%= %>`.

Comment: Although, you will need a semi colon at the end of the Response.Write Statement.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on personal XP with MVC4 cshtml - you can use:
    `@Html.Raw("SomeStringDirectlyInsideTheBrowserPageHTMLCode")`

This renders the (dynamic) string at its position unlike `Response.Write(MyString)` which as far as I've noticed always renders the string at the begining of the browser-page.

Note that the HTML tags rendered by `@Html.Raw(MyString)` cannot be checked by the compiler. I mean: @Html.Raw("<div ....>") cannot be closed by mere </div> because you will get an error (<div ....> is not detected by the compiler) so you must close the tag with @Html.Raw("</div>")

P.S.
In some cases this doesn't work (for example it fails within DevExpress) - use `ViewContext.Writer.Write()` or `ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine()` instead.

Comment: I think this is the correct method for Razor engine.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably a different View engine -- they each handle embedded code like that in their own way. Check out [NHaml](http://andrewpeters.net/2007/12/19/introducing-nhaml-an-aspnet-mvc-view-engine/), an ASP.Net port of Rails' [Haml](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/) engine.

Some more view engines to look at: [Brail](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Brail&referringTitle=Documentation),
[NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,I dont specifically want to switch view engines, though I will take time to look at the other avaliable. I am sure you can understand that most MS development houses dont touch anything but MS branded technology so I just wanted to know if there was a way to do this with the default view engine. Or if not, why not? Is there a reason, if not where could I suggest the default view compiler add such a keywork.

John- I believe that Response.Write(Person.Name) will just render the string to the top of the page, before any other output. Not 100% on that though, ill give it a bash.

Edit:

Apparently, Response.Write(Person.Name) works as suggested. Well that was easy. Thanks :-) John.

Comment: Check http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-04-cs.aspx. <%= %> is a shortcut for Response.Write.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard they're working on improving this for ASP.Net 4 via client templates.

Answer (score 0):

Another option other than Response.Write would be to write XHtml with [XSL transformations](http://weblogs.asp.net/jigardesai/archive/2008/02/08/xslt-transformation-in-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx)

Comment: True, but why make it more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: I didn't say it was a good option :) Using a different View engine would be much preferable to XSLT. But who knows; maybe somewhere out there there's a situation to which XSLT is ideally suited. It could happen.